# Tricky groupby/moving average by date calculation

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, moving-average

I am having trouble illustrating my problem with the form the data is in without complicating things. So bear with me as I would like to start with the following screen shot is for explaining the problem only (aka the data is not in this form) :

[image]

I would like to identify the past 14 days with a number > 0 across all bins (aka the total row has a value greater than 0). This would include all days except for days 5 and 12 (highlighted in red). I would then like to sum across bins horizontally for those 14 days (aka sum all days expect for 5 and 12, by bin), with the goal of ultimately calculating a 14 day average by Bin number.

Note the example above would be for one “Lane”, where my data has > 10,000. The example also only illustrates today being day 16. But I would like to apply this logic to every day in the data set. I.e. on day 20 (along with any other date), it would look at the last 14 days with a value across all bins, then use that data range to aggregate across Bin. This is a screenshot sample of how the data looks:

[image]

A simple example using the data as it is structured, with only 3 Bins, 1 Lane, and a 3 data point/date look back:

```
Lane    Date        Bin KG
AMS-ORD 2018-08-26  3   10
AMS-ORD 2018-08-29  1   25
AMS-ORD 2018-08-30  2   30
AMS-ORD 2018-09-03  2   20
AMS-ORD 2018-09-04  1   40
```

Note KG here is a sum. Again this is for one day (aka today), but I would like every date in my data set to follow the same logic. The output would look like the following:

```
Lane    Date        Bin KG  Average
AMS-ORD 2018-09-04  1   40   13.33 
AMS-ORD 2018-09-04  2   50   16.67 
AMS-ORD 2018-09-04  3   0    -
```

I have messed around with .rolling(14).mean(), .tail(), and some others. The problem I have is specifying the correct date range for the correct Bin aggregation.

Comment: Not quite clear to me .

Comment: "bin" in the upper corresponds with "lane" in the lower part?

Comment: @Wen, in simple terms: I want to take a 14 data point average by Bin. I want the 14 data points in this average calculation to be limited by date (which would be the last 14 days with any KG across all Bins). I think the first screenshot explains the issue best in my opinion.

Comment: @MartinSeehafer No bin does not correspond to lane.